# How can I map the integer to corresponding text?

Tags: django, django-templates

In the templates, there is a `data.grade` which is integer.

If the data.grade == 1, I want to the place shows `VIP`, if equals to `2`, I want to shows `Normal`

```
{{ data.grade }} # there only shows 1 or 2, but I want to shows VIP or Normal
```

---

I am looking a succinct method to do that, because I think the `if else` is too clutter here, if I have 50 possible values.

Answer (score 0):

The method Robert suggested will work but as you said you have 50+ values, an `if-elif` approach would slow down the rendering of the page. You are better off with calculating the mapping in the `views.py` before you render. Something that you could do is:

```
list_of_possible_values = ['VIP','Normal','lorem','ipsum']
#The list above can be as long as you want it to be
data_object = 'Query your data object here'
value_to_display = list_of_possible_values[data_object.grade-1]
return render('your_html_file',{'value_to_display':value_to_display}
```

I am looking up the value to display from a list based on the index number. If you wish to render multiple `data` objects, you can add the code above in a loop and return a list of `value_to_display` strings to the page to render.

Hope this helps!